# JSF 1.2 IBM JWL ajax components (hx:ajaxRefreshSubmit, hx:ajaxRefreshRequest) problems with IE11

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-1.2, ibm-jsf

I have a problem with ajax components hx:ajaxRefreshSubmit and hx:ajaxRefreshRequest on IE11. Both of them are working only on the first submit - request.

I use the latest version of JWL and Portlet Bridge (jsf-ibm.jar v 3.1.20, jsf-portletbridge.jar v 3.1.19).
Ajax works on all browsers (IE9, IE10, latest Chrome, latest Firefox, Microsoft Edge) except on IE11.

Has anyone managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Our JSF1.2/JWL project has also been pushed onto IE11. Running the page in compatibility mode seems to solve our issues.

I also found a solution which involves changing the JSP with a directive to work as IE<11 on this page [IBM Developer Works](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/219700/since-upgrading-to-newer-browswer-versions-we-have.html) although I haven't tried it yet.